# change font color of link button in asp.net through CSS with hover properties

Tags: css, asplinkbutton

I want to change color of link button so I made CSS like this:

```
.stylink 
a
{ font:10px; color:white;  }

a:hover
{ font:12px; color:#ff0; }
```

I have link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_gvinfo" runat="server" 
Text="arshad" CssClass="stylink" Font-Underline="false" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

This `a:hover` property of CSS works but `a` dosn't work. When I point cursor on link button it becomes yellow, but after that it remains blue.

Comment: @JaredReisinger how did u set background of text a:hover and a ?

Comment: You can use the `background` or `background-color` CSS properties.

Comment: Are you asking how "a:hover" and "a" got the background within StackOverflow itself (in the sentence after the code sample, above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a `.stylink a` selector, try `.stylink a:link` to set the color of a hyperlink.  You may also wanted to take a look at the `a:visited` and `a:active` selectors to handle the "has already been clicked on or visited", and "has the current keyboard (tab) focus" cases, respectively.

Comment: thanx for this
but one more thing that i asked  u in my comment that how do u set grey background posting question or comment on this site

Answer (score 1):

Brother..
You can Apply Hover Like this.

```
.stylink 
{ font:10px; color:white;  }

.stylink:hover
{ font:12px; color:#ff0; }
```